# Running java application in Intellij, stuck on: HikariPool-1 - Starting

Tags: java, docker, mariadb

If I for instance need to restart my session in Intellij, I always get stuck here, I believe it has something to do with my db, which is a mariadb running in docker. Only solution so far is to reboot my computer, rather drastic solution I think.

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                      NAMES
c54527dea5d8        mariadb             "docker-entrypoint.s…"   2 months ago        Up About an hour    127.0.0.1:3306->3306/tcp   suspicious_sinoussi
```

## #

```
:: Spring Boot ::        (v2.0.1.RELEASE)

2019-01-29 18:19:02.921  INFO 3979 --- [           main] c.netapp.qronicle.QronicleApplicationKt  : Starting QronicleApplicationKt on jmasson-mac-0 with PID 3979 (/Users/jonma/Development/java/report-generator/target/classes started by jonma in /Users/jonma/Development/java/report-generator)
2019-01-29 18:19:02.980  INFO 3979 --- [           main] c.netapp.qronicle.QronicleApplicationKt  : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2019-01-29 18:19:03.295  INFO 3979 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@1ed6388a: startup date [Tue Jan 29 18:19:03 GMT 2019]; root of context hierarchy
2019-01-29 18:19:07.020  INFO 3979 --- [           main] f.a.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor : JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
2019-01-29 18:19:07.570  INFO 3979 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 9096 (http)
2019-01-29 18:19:07.601  INFO 3979 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2019-01-29 18:19:07.601  INFO 3979 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.29
2019-01-29 18:19:07.613  INFO 3979 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [/Users/jonma/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:.]
2019-01-29 18:19:07.753  INFO 3979 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2019-01-29 18:19:07.753  INFO 3979 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 4459 ms
2019-01-29 18:19:08.679  INFO 3979 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Servlet dispatcherServlet mapped to [/]
2019-01-29 18:19:08.684  INFO 3979 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2019-01-29 18:19:08.685  INFO 3979 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpTraceFilter' to: [/*]
2019-01-29 18:19:08.685  INFO 3979 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'webMvcMetricsFilter' to: [/*]
2019-01-29 18:19:08.747  INFO 3979 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
```

added `debug` to `zaxxer.hikar`

```
----------> Parent Classloader:
sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@18b4aac2

2019-01-29 18:45:36.680  INFO 4407 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Servlet dispatcherServlet mapped to [/]
2019-01-29 18:45:36.685  INFO 4407 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2019-01-29 18:45:36.686  INFO 4407 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpTraceFilter' to: [/*]
2019-01-29 18:45:36.687  INFO 4407 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'webMvcMetricsFilter' to: [/*]
2019-01-29 18:45:36.749 DEBUG 4407 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : HikariPool-1 - configuration:
2019-01-29 18:45:36.752 DEBUG 4407 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : allowPoolSuspension.............false
2019-01-29 18:45:36.752 DEBUG 4407 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : autoCommit......................true
2019-01-29 18:45:36.752 DEBUG 4407 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : catalog.........................none
2019-01-29 18:45:36.752 DEBUG 4407 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : connectionInitSql...............none
2019-01-29 18:45:36.752 DEBUG 4407 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : connectionTestQuery.............none
2019-01-29 18:45:36.752 DEBUG 4407 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : connectionTimeout...............30000
2019-01-29 18:45:36.752 DEBUG 4407 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : dataSource......................none
2019-01-29 18:45:36.752 DEBUG 4407 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : dataSourceClassName.............none
2019-01-29 18:45:36.752 DEBUG 4407 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : dataSourceJNDI..................none
2019-01-29 18:45:36.753 DEBUG 4407 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : dataSourceProperties............{password=<masked>}
2019-01-29 18:45:36.753 DEBUG 4407 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : driverClassName................."org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver"
2019-01-29 18:45:36.753 DEBUG 4407 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : healthCheckProperties...........{}
2019-01-29 18:45:36.753 DEBUG 4407 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : healthCheckRegistry.............none
2019-01-29 18:45:36.753 DEBUG 4407 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : idleTimeout.....................600000
2019-01-29 18:45:36.754 DEBUG 4407 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : initializationFailFast..........true
2019-01-29 18:45:36.754 DEBUG 4407 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : initializationFailTimeout.......1
2019-01-29 18:45:36.754 DEBUG 4407 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : isolateInternalQueries..........false
2019-01-29 18:45:36.754 DEBUG 4407 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : jdbc4ConnectionTest.............false
2019-01-29 18:45:36.754 DEBUG 4407 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : jdbcUrl.........................jdbc:mysql://localhost/qronicle?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
2019-01-29 18:45:36.754 DEBUG 4407 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : leakDetectionThreshold..........0
2019-01-29 18:45:36.754 DEBUG 4407 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : maxLifetime.....................1800000
2019-01-29 18:45:36.754 DEBUG 4407 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : maximumPoolSize.................10
2019-01-29 18:45:36.755 DEBUG 4407 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : metricRegistry..................none
2019-01-29 18:45:36.755 DEBUG 4407 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : metricsTrackerFactory...........com.zaxxer.hikari.metrics.micrometer.MicrometerMetricsTrackerFactory@68b366e2
2019-01-29 18:45:36.755 DEBUG 4407 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : minimumIdle.....................10
2019-01-29 18:45:36.755 DEBUG 4407 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : password........................<masked>
2019-01-29 18:45:36.755 DEBUG 4407 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : poolName........................"HikariPool-1"
2019-01-29 18:45:36.755 DEBUG 4407 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : readOnly........................false
2019-01-29 18:45:36.755 DEBUG 4407 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : registerMbeans..................false
2019-01-29 18:45:36.755 DEBUG 4407 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : scheduledExecutor...............none
2019-01-29 18:45:36.755 DEBUG 4407 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : scheduledExecutorService........internal
2019-01-29 18:45:36.755 DEBUG 4407 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : schema..........................none
2019-01-29 18:45:36.755 DEBUG 4407 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : threadFactory...................internal
2019-01-29 18:45:36.756 DEBUG 4407 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : transactionIsolation............default
2019-01-29 18:45:36.756 DEBUG 4407 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : username........................"root"
2019-01-29 18:45:36.756 DEBUG 4407 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : validationTimeout...............5000
2019-01-29 18:45:36.756  INFO 4407 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
```

Comment: Could you please provide a thread dump with threads relevant for hikari at least so that we could see where exactly it gets stuck? Series of thread dumps over time could show the progress as well. Another (additional) option is printing all sql statements...

Comment: @MarkBramnik sorry for the stupid follow up question, rather new in Java, how can I add this information that you mentioned?

Answer (score -2):

You can restart docker. there is no need to restart your PC.
This problem appears with the new docker version. try using an older one like 18.06.1

Same problem found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56286104/spring-boot-application-gets-stuck-on-hikari-pool-1-starting)

Does someone know how to fix this problem?