# Spring Boot Application gets stuck on “Hikari-Pool-1 - Starting…”

Tags: spring, postgresql, docker

I'm trying to run Spring Boot application connected to PostgreSQL database, but it just gets stuck and nothing goes on. 
HikariPool-1 - Starting... appears in logs and then nothing happens. 
And I deploy my Postgres DB as a docker image but when I try to restart the database, it stucks also and can't restart. And the problem appears in log is:  statistics instead of current ones because stats collector is not responding

Maybe it relates with large I/O, because sometimes I need to fetch at least 65000 rows of data one time and also add pagination in the backend. Since there should have a lot of workloads to do, maybe the server is overloaded. And I find the exception on the log said using stale “statistics instead of current ones because stats collector is not responding” which is usually caused by the database is overloaded.

```
exec java -Dspring.profiles.active=docker -XX:+UseParallelGC -XX:GCTimeRatio=4 -XX:AdaptiveSizePolicyWeight=90 -XX:MinHeapFreeRatio=20 -XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=40 -XX:+ExitOnOutOfMemoryError -cp . -jar /deployments/app.jar
. ____ _ __ _ _
/\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __ __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
\\/ ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| | ) ) ) )
' |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
=========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
:: Spring Boot :: (v2.0.1.RELEASE)
2019-05-23 00:34:21.142 INFO 1 --- [ main] com.auth.wisat.WisatApplication : Starting WisatApplication v0.1.5 on api-8554d5fd4c-wqrpb with PID 1 (/deployments/app.jar started by root in /deployments)
2019-05-23 00:34:21.144 INFO 1 --- [ main] com.auth.wisat.WisatApplication : The following profiles are active: docker
2019-05-23 00:34:21.185 INFO 1 --- [ main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@44e81672: startup date [Thu May 23 00:34:21 GMT 2019]; root of context hierarchy
2019-05-23 00:34:23.024 INFO 1 --- [ main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ca1676b3] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2019-05-23 00:34:23.189 INFO 1 --- [ main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.configuration.ObjectPostProcessorConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.security.config.annotation.configuration.ObjectPostProcessorConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$62c43eed] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2019-05-23 00:34:23.196 INFO 1 --- [ main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'objectPostProcessor' of type [org.springframework.security.config.annotation.configuration.AutowireBeanFactoryObjectPostProcessor] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2019-05-23 00:34:23.198 INFO 1 --- [ main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler@173ed316' of type [org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2019-05-23 00:34:23.201 INFO 1 --- [ main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$8798e19f] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2019-05-23 00:34:23.209 INFO 1 --- [ main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'methodSecurityMetadataSource' of type [org.springframework.security.access.method.DelegatingMethodSecurityMetadataSource] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2019-05-23 00:34:23.457 INFO 1 --- [ main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2019-05-23 00:34:23.483 INFO 1 --- [ main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService : Starting service [Tomcat]
2019-05-23 00:34:23.483 INFO 1 --- [ main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.29
2019-05-23 00:34:23.492 INFO 1 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener : The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/jre/lib/amd64/server:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/jre/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/jre/../lib/amd64:/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib]
2019-05-23 00:34:23.647 INFO 1 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/] : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2019-05-23 00:34:23.647 INFO 1 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2464 ms
2019-05-23 00:34:24.528 INFO 1 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2019-05-23 00:34:24.528 INFO 1 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2019-05-23 00:34:24.529 INFO 1 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2019-05-23 00:34:24.529 INFO 1 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2019-05-23 00:34:24.529 INFO 1 --- [ost-startStop-1] .s.DelegatingFilterProxyRegistrationBean : Mapping filter: 'springSecurityFilterChain' to: [/*]
2019-05-23 00:34:24.529 INFO 1 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean : Mapping filter: 'httpTraceFilter' to: [/*]
2019-05-23 00:34:24.529 INFO 1 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean : Mapping filter: 'webMvcMetricsFilter' to: [/*]
2019-05-23 00:34:24.529 INFO 1 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean : Mapping filter: 'authenticationTokenFilter' to: [/*]
2019-05-23 00:34:24.529 INFO 1 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean : Servlet dispatcherServlet mapped to [/]
2019-05-23 00:34:24.619 INFO 1 --- [ main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
```

postgres log

```
LOG: using stale statistics instead of current ones because stats collector is not responding
LOG: using stale statistics instead of current ones because stats collector is not responding
LOG: using stale statistics instead of current ones because stats collector is not responding
LOG: using stale statistics instead of current ones because stats collector is not responding
LOG: using stale statistics instead of current ones because stats collector is not responding
LOG: using stale statistics instead of current ones because stats collector is not responding
LOG: using stale statistics instead of current ones because stats collector is not responding
LOG: using stale statistics instead of current ones because stats collector is not responding
LOG: using stale statistics instead of current ones because stats collector is not responding
LOG: using stale statistics instead of current ones because stats collector is not responding
LOG: using stale statistics instead of current ones because stats collector is not responding
LOG: using stale statistics instead of current ones because stats collector is not responding
LOG: using stale statistics instead of current ones because stats collector is not responding
LOG: using stale statistics instead of current ones because stats collector is not responding
LOG: using stale statistics instead of current ones because stats collector is not responding
LOG: using stale statistics instead of current ones because stats collector is not responding
LOG: using stale statistics instead of current ones because stats collector is not responding
LOG: using stale statistics instead of current ones because stats collector is not responding
LOG: using stale statistics instead of current ones because stats collector is not responding
LOG: using stale statistics instead of current ones because stats collector is not responding
LOG: using stale statistics instead of current ones because stats collector is not responding
```

My pom.xml:

```
<properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <springfox-swagger.version>2.9.2</springfox-swagger.version>
        <jjwt.version>0.9.0</jjwt.version>
        <postgresql.version>9.4-1206-jdbc42</postgresql.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>${postgresql.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--<dependency>-->
            <!--<groupId>com.h2database</groupId>-->
            <!--<artifactId>h2</artifactId>-->
            <!--<scope>runtime</scope>-->
        <!--</dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.16.22</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>${springfox-swagger.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>${springfox-swagger.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>${jjwt.version}</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

My apllication.properties:

```
spring.datasource.username=${POSTGRES_USER:postgres}
spring.datasource.password=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD:123}
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.platform=postgres
# Keep the connection alive if idle for a long time (needed in production)
spring.datasource.testWhileIdle=true
spring.datasource.validationQuery=SELECT 1
# ===============================
# = JPA / HIBERNATE
# ===============================
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=false
# Show or not log for each sql query
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, update): with "create-drop" the database
# schema will be automatically created afresh for every start of application
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate

# Naming strategy
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.implicit-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyLegacyHbmImpl
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy
#disable exceptions
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults=false


# Allows Hibernate to generate SQL optimized for a particular DBMS
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect

spring.jackson.serialization.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS = false
spring.jackson.date-format = com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.util.ISO8601DateFormat
```

How can I solve the issue? 
basically I think it is because of the connection pool leaks, any one have experience with it? 
And for spring, is there a good way to design a restful API with large data request?

Comment: I can not see the maxPoolSize defined anywhere in your application.properties?

Comment: I didn't define the maxPoolSize in the application.properties, it should use the default one 100

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Boot Application gets stuck on "Hikari-Pool-1 - Starting..."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51242938/spring-boot-application-gets-stuck-on-hikari-pool-1-starting)